# How to use `migration.jar` in Corda Enterprise 4 to run tests?

Tags: corda

While using **Corda Enterprise 4.2**, we have managed to create a
`biz-generated-migration....jar` which seems to be a pre-requisite to everything, even
when using an H2 database. We were not able to use this `.jar` file
while executing our tests, even when referencing this brand new `.jar`
file in our test setup, like this:

```
  val BIZ_COMPONENT_VERSION="1.0.0"
  val DEFAULT_MOCK_NETWORK = MockNetwork(
          cordappPackages = listOf(
                  "package.subpkg-infra.cd.contract",
                  "package.subpkg-infra.contract",
                  "package.subpkg-infra.flow",
                  "package.subpkg-infra.cd.flow",
                  "package.subpkg-infra.cd.pend.flow",
                  "package.subpkg-infra.schema",
                  "package.subpkg-cordapp:biz-generated-migration:$BIZ_COMPONENT_VERSION",
                  "package.subpkg-cordapp:biz-component-base:$BIZ_COMPONENT_VERSION",
                  "package.subpkg-cordapp:biz-component-core:$BIZ_COMPONENT_VERSION",
                  "package.subpkg-cordapp:biz-component-interact:$BIZ_COMPONENT_VERSION"
          ),
          notarySpecs = listOf(MockNetworkNotarySpec(DUMMY_NOTARY_NAME)))
```

Every test fails, complaining about not finding the migration for the
schema.

How can we accomplish to use this generated `migration.jar` file to
enable our testing ? Or is this approach completely misused ?

Comment: Have you added this migration.jar to the cordapps directory? Rather the question can be where is the generated migration.jar kept, in which folder. Also once you generate your migration script did you fire the below command to generate the migration.jar.jar cvf /path/to/node/cordapps/biz-generated-migration.jar migration

Comment: Hi, Sneha. The main point is, while executing the testing phase, we should not need the cordapps folder at all. All our efforts were made in some *trial-and-error* way. In the 3.X enterprise version, we could create tests without bothering with the cordapps folder. Since 4.X enterprise, we need to add some .sql into the project resources, generated with the DatabaseMigration tool. It solves the test phase but, as this file becomes integrated in the resulting cordapp, we get stuch on the h2 schema.

Comment: In order to switch the resulting cordapp to any other backing database, we need to manually delete the .sql file from that cordapp, which will break its SHA256 hash and force us to always clean up the resulting database prior to the node startup.

Comment: can you confirm on below points: 1. Have you overridden the "migrationResourse"="migration/filename"  of MappedSchema class. 2. make sure to proper XML so this would be not H2 specific. 3. also could you try to use below network = MockNetwork(MockNetworkParameters(listOf(
       findCordapp("com.deqode.contracts"),
       findCordapp("com.deqode.flows")))
) instead of cordappPackages. 4. Can you confirm if you are using Windows

Comment: Hi there, Sneha. 1. We had actually not altered this setting ; 2. All JPA mapping was done thru annotations, we didn't use any xml mapping; 4. We are using both Windows and Linux for dev / compiling / test; 3. As soon as we can try you suggestion, we'll get back to you.

Comment: Hi any updates ? also I have pinged you on slack , so if you could please take a look at slack as well.

Comment: Hello did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

Following options have been suggested to fix the issue.

1. Have you overridden the "migrationResourse"="migration/filename" of MappedSchema class.
2. make sure to proper XML so this would be not H2 specific.
3. also could you try to use below network = MockNetwork(MockNetworkParameters(listOf( findCordapp("com.deqode.contracts"), findCordapp("com.deqode.flows"))) ) instead of cordappPackages.
4. Can you confirm if you are using Windows